# Install error in android emulator with react native: Could not open settings remapped class cache for po6n8851p0t5646j48cpt24i

Tags: android, android-emulator, react-native

1.
Summarize the problem

I joined in the middle of developing an application through react native so I tried to compile on Android emulator.
When I run `$ react-native run-android`,the emulator works but the app is not installed.
The build works fine on other team members' laptops, but not on mine.
The error message is:

```
MacBook-Pro-3:react-native-starter seunghyunwoo$ react-native run-android
```

warn Your project is using deprecated "rnpm" config that will stop working from next release. Please use a "react-native.config.js" file to configure the React Native CLI. Migration guide: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/configuration.md
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1638 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info Starting JS server...
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
info Launching emulator...
info Successfully launched emulator.
info Installing the app...
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not open settings remapped class cache for po6n8851p0t5646j48cpt24i (/Users/seunghyunwoo/.gradle/caches/5.5/scripts-remapped/settings_7eu19g7uwjl23ikwbk0j0slts/po6n8851p0t5646j48cpt24i/settings74e694b976d6abaa826c8abac43e9de8).

  > Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file '/Users/seunghyunwoo/mecute/playground/react-native-starter/android/settings.gradle' (/Users/seunghyunwoo/.gradle/caches/5.5/scripts/po6n8851p0t5646j48cpt24i/settings/settings74e694b976d6abaa826c8abac43e9de8).
  >   BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 57
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not open settings remapped class cache for po6n8851p0t5646j48cpt24i (/Users/seunghyunwoo/.gradle/caches/5.5/scripts-remapped/settings_7eu19g7uwjl23ikwbk0j0slts/po6n8851p0t5646j48cpt24i/settings74e694b976d6abaa826c8abac43e9de8).

  > Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file '/Users/seunghyunwoo/mecute/playground/react-native-starter/android/settings.gradle' (/Users/seunghyunwoo/.gradle/caches/5.5/scripts/po6n8851p0t5646j48cpt24i/settings/settings74e694b976d6abaa826c8abac43e9de8).
  >   BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 57
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s

```
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:611:11)
at execFileSync (child_process.js:629:15)
at runOnAllDevices (/Users/seunghyunwoo/mecute/playground/react-native-starter/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:94:39)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
at async Command.handleAction (/Users/seunghyunwoo/mecute/playground/react-native-starter/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:164:9)
```

2.
Describe what you’ve tried

I remove caches directory and files in it but errors still occured.
Here's my environment:

```
System:
OS: macOS 10.15.2
CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7820HQ CPU @ 2.90GHz
Memory: 94.54 MB / 16.00 GB
Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
```

Binaries:
    Node: 13.8.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.21.1 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.13.6 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: iOS 13.2, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.2, watchOS 6.1
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 3.5 AI-191.8026.42.35.6010548
    Xcode: 11.3.1/11C504 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  npmPackages:
    react: 16.12.0 => 16.12.0 
    react-native: 0.61.5 => 0.61.5 
  npmGlobalPackages:
    react-native-cli: 2.0.1

How can I fix this?
please help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved this by installing JDK 8. I was experiencing this issue with JDK 13.

You can remove current installed JDK with (MacOS):

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk<version>.jdk
```

Then go to the official Oracle download page (you need to create an account):

[JDK 1.8 Download](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html)

Comment: Somehow it's solved. Thanks for your help though :)

Comment: No need to uninstall anything. Download java 8 and change the path with `export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`` to switch back if you need to at a later stage

Comment: Yes, changing the $JAVA_HOME path variable to jdk1.8<version code>.jdk works for me.

Comment: Find installed Java versions and use one of those `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` to find and then like @Dazzle said use that command to switch.

Answer (score -3):

Try disable Avast

I'm using react native